# MPV player keys don't work on video

Tags: lubuntu, video, brightness

I am using `mpv` with Lubuntu 18.04 and the keys 1-8 don't work on videos.

These keys should adjust contrast, brightness, gamma and saturation. When I press the keys, I can see a bar for the corresponding setting going up or down, but this has no effect on the video. Maybe I am missing a package for this settings to work? I was using Linux Mint XFCE 19 a few days back and these keys were working. Thanks.

Comment: Hi raidensub! What do you exactly mean by keys 1-8. Is it your function keys or the standard keys as listed in the `man mpv` ?

Comment: The standard keys 1-8 from mpv input.    https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/etc/input.conf

Answer (score 2):

It works now. I had to edit the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-graphics.conf` and add `Option "AccelMethod" "sna"` and `Option "DRI" "2"`. The keys didn't work because I was using software rendering for the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Running `mpv -vo opengl` instead of the default (`mpv -vo vaapi`) has solved this for me. Other video drivers haven't.

The full list of video drivers (including *opengl* and *vaapi*) is available in the output of `mpv -vo help`.